# Как сделать scrollview, растущий и скролющийся вверх?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollview, android-linearlayout, messenger

Моя проблема в том, что я добавляю новые сообщения в LinearLayout, а ScrollView имеет свойство "уезжать" вверх каждый раз. Или, к примеру, открытая клавиатура заставляет скролл проседать под нее. Я пробовал использовать layout_gravity bottom, что давало нужный мне результат, но при этом не работает скролл. По сути мой вопрос заключается в том, как из **layout_gravity** **bottom** разрешить **скролл** вверх. Вот мой xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/messscroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messagebox"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"

        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator"
        android:dividerPadding="3dp"

        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="1px"
        android:showDividers="middle"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко - не использовать LinearLayout. Для списков с потенциально большим количеством элементов используйте RecyclerView и ему подобные. Обучалок по нему уйма, погуглите, если будут с ним проблемы - создавайте соответствующие вопросы.

В самом RecyclerView надо сделать его "обратным", чтобы начало было внизу. Делается это в LayoutManager

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

теперь по мере надобности добавляем в конец списка сообщения и сообщаем об этом адаптеру нашего RecyclerView с помощью метода notifyItemInserted(position)